# Change textbox background colour based on value

Tags: background, textbox

Hi i have a textbox field which can have a number between 1 - 6 or more.
1-3 is green
4-5 is orange
6 or more is red

this field auto calculates based on value selected from other fields.

```
function changeColour() {
if (document.getElementById("Q49I1029").value > 0) {  
document.getElementById("Q49I1029").style.background = '#00FF33'; // Green
}
else if (document.getElementById("Q49I1029").value > 3) {
document.getElementById("Q49I1029").style.background = '#EC582D'; // Orange
}
else (document.getElementById("Q49I1029").value > 5) {
document.getElementById("Q49I1029").style.background = '#990000'; // Reg
}
alert ("This box must be filled!");
document.getElementById("Q49I1029").focus();
return false;
}
```

but i am unable to get this to work. 
any help will be much appriciated.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IF statement only for all condition.

Remove "else if" and "else".

Comment: thanks, it works now, but the colour does not change automatically when the value in the text box changes. it changes only when i focus on it. i have put the function in the onBlur=changeColour();' and  onChange="changeColour();" event.

Comment: when focus is lost , then it will change the colour. wht do u exactly want ?

Comment: the value changes as i select the other questions, but the color does not change. there is no focus in the feild at all when the value changes. how do i enable the focus for this field when the value changes? thanks

Comment: call this function after whenever you select other questions.